# Proving that the intersection of two regular surfaces is a regular curve

Tags: differential-geometry, solution-verification, curves, surfaces

I'm having some trouble with the following problem:

> Let $S_1$ and $S_2$ be two regular surfaces that intersect at a point $p$, such that $T_pS_1\neq T_pS_2$. Prove that there is an open neighborhood $U\subseteq\mathbb R^3$ of $p$ such that $S_1 \cap S_2\cap U$ is the trace of a regular curve.

---

My first idea was to use the fact that, because $S_1$ and $S_2$ are regular surfaces, there are open neighborhoods $W,V$ in $\mathbb R^3$ of $p$ and $f:W\to\mathbb R$, $g:V\to\mathbb R$ differentiable, such that:$$W\cap S_1=f^{-1}(\{0\})$$
$$V\cap S_2=g^{-1}(\{0\})$$
So with this, we can conclude, if we set $U=W\cap V$, that $S_1\cap S_2\cap U$ is defined by the following system of equations:
$$f(x,y,z)=0$$
$$g(x,y,z)=0$$

This is a system with 2 equations and 3 variables, so my intuition tells me that the solution will have 1 free variable, and thus be a curve, but I have no idea how to formalize this.

---

My second idea was the following:
If $T_pS_1$ and $T_pS_2$ intersect and are not the same, then $T_pS_1\cap T_pS_2$ is a one-dimensional linear subspace of $\mathbb R^3$, let it be the space generated by the vector $v$. Now we know a vector that will be tangent to the curve we want to find. Maybe with this, we can construct the curve?

---

Does any of these ideas work? If that's now the case, how can this be done?

Answer (score 1):

**Hint (for approach 1):** Notice that $$F : U \mapsto \Bbb R^2, \qquad F : (x, y, z) \mapsto (f(x, y, z), g(x, y, z))$$ is a differentiable function with zero set $\Sigma := U \cap S_1 \cap S_2$, so to show that $\Sigma$ a smooth curve, it's sufficient to check that $F$ has constant rank $2$ along $\Sigma$, i.e., that $df \wedge dg$ vanishes nowhere on $\Sigma$. This property is not automatic for $f$ and $g$ as in the question statement, but notice that we can furthermore insist that our choice of defining functions $f, g$ satisfies $df \neq 0$, $dg \neq 0$ along $\Sigma$. Then, transversality guarantees that $df \wedge dg \neq 0$ there.

Comment: what does $df, dg$ and $\wedge$ mean in this context?

Comment: The symbols $df$ and $dg$ denote the differentials of $f, g$, respectively, and $\wedge$ denotes the wedge product. See: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Differential_form

Since we're in the real setting, we can identify $df, dg$ respectively with the gradient vector fields of $f, g$. In that language, our condition is that $(\operatorname{grad} f)_p$ and $(\operatorname{grad} g)_p$ are not parallel for any $p \in \Sigma$.

Comment: Do you have any other ideas on how to solve this? I don't understand your answer since I'm not familiar with these concepts

Comment: The notion of gradient here is just the familiar one from vector calculus, but it's perhaps better known in that context by the symbol $\nabla$. In terms of the pushforward maps $T_p F: T_p \Bbb R^3 \to T_{F(p)} \Bbb R^2$ the condition is just that $T_p F$ is surjective (i.e., rank $2$) for all $p \in \Sigma$. If that's not helpful either, what are the tools you have available?

Comment: ah, I think I get it. And we can conclude that $\nabla f(p)$ and $\nabla g(p)$ are linearly independent because $T_pS_1\neq T_pS_2$ right?

Comment: Yes---in fact, $T_p S_1 = (\nabla f)(p)^\perp$ and likewise for $S_2$.